# Система не видит SSD

Tags: ос, ssd

На данный момент на компе две системы ( dual boot ) - Windows 10 и  Ubuntu.
У каждой системы свой ssd диск. Проблема в том, что обе системы работают хорошо, но из винды я почему-то не вижу в проводнике диск, на котором Ubuntu. А так же невидно этого диска и в Bios.

В чем может быть проблема?

```
DISKPART> list disk

Диск ###  Состояние      Размер   Свободно Дин  GPT
--------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
Диск 0    В сети          119 Gбайт      0 байт        * // тут винда
Диск 1    В сети          465 Gбайт  1024 Kбайт        * // тут линь
```

[image: Упарвление дисками]

Comment: Там различные файловые системы. А windows кроме своих никого не признает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там различные файловые системы и разбивка дисков.
А windows никого не признает кроме FAT, NTFS, exFAT, Live File System и ReFS